# Nested types in clojure?

Tags: clojure, deftype

In clojure, how do I type type hint a type that I have created?  (I want to nest the types.)

e.g.  I had thought that this would work:

```
(deftype A 
    [#^somePrimitive  someField])

(deftype B
    [#^A Avalue])
```

This brings up an error message:

```
Unknown location:
  error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A
```

Note: clojure types are a new feature which currently exists only in the 'new' branch of clojure.

**Edit:** I was confused by the different ways of type hinting in clojure for java and clojure types.
java classes are hinted as

```
#^java.some.class
```

while clojure types are hinted as:

```
#^:some.Namespace/type
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For each deftype, a type tag (basically a namespace-qualified keyword) is created so you don't have to AOT-compile your code before you can use the resulting class.

If type A is in the current namespace, you can write it like this:

```
(deftype B [^::A Avalue])
```

For types in other namespaces, qualify the keyword using its namespace:

```
(deftype B [^:user/A Avalue])
```

Answer (score 3):

(deftype B [#^:user/A Avalue]) works for me.

Comment: That seems to work, but then how would I do the same thing in other files? +1, anyhow.

Comment: Yup, I figured it out now.  Thanks alot.